# How can you use the word "stupid" as a noun?

Tags: meaning, articles, adjectives, nouns

How can you use the word "stupid" with the article as a noun?

> Stupid

Wikipedia has the meaning (noun informal).

Comment: The clever will survive while the stupid are left to their fate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "the {adjective}" can be used to refer to a collection of people (for instance) who all share that characteristic:

> Only the brave will enter...
>
> The meek shall inherit the earth...

Thus, `stupid` can be used as a noun to mean a group of people who are all stupid.